# Adding an item to contextmenu in FireFox

Tags: firefox-addon

Im trying to add a new item to the Context Menu in firefox after right clicking an image.
I already read the docs in the webpage of Mozilla.
in the XUL file i have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="emailpicture" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://firefoxextension/content/emailpicture.js"/>

<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menuitem id="emailpicture" label="Email This Image" oncommand=""/>
</popup>
</overlay>
```

In the chrome.manifest i have this code:

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://firefoxextension/content/myext.xul
```

When i run Firefox, it didn't add any item.
it seems like Firefox doesn't even run `myext.xul`.
what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's `<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu">`, not `popup`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed it, but still nothing happens. btw, in the closing tags, i have to change it as well, right ?

Comment: Yes, you have to change the closing tag too.